# Changing code to data in radare2

Tags: radare2

I really like radare2 and I am trying to follow a tutorial in which some code is changed to data. The tutorial uses IDA, I have tryed this with radare2. I entered visual mode by pressing `V` and cursor mode by pressing `c`. I stepped to the code which I want to modify.

```
|           0x00400440   *  31ed           xorl %ebp, %ebp             ; [12] va=0x00400440 pa=0x00000440 sz=386 vsz= 
|           0x00400442      4989d1         movq %rdx, %r9
```

After pressing `dd` the following output appeared:

```
0x00400440 hex length=175 delta=0                                                                         
0x00400440 |31ed 4989 d15e 4889 e248 83e4 f050 5449| 1.I..^H..H...PTI                                                 
0x00400450 |c7c0 c005 4000 48c7 c150 0540 0048 c7c7| ....@.H..P.@.H..                                                 
0x00400460 |3605 4000 e8b7 ffff fff4 660f 1f44 0000| 6.@.......f..D..                                                 
0x00400470 |b847 1060 0055 482d 4010 6000 4883 f80e| .G.`.UH-@.`.H...                                                 
0x00400480 |4889 e576 1bb8 0000 0000 4885 c074 115d| H..v......H..t.]                                                 
0x00400490 |bf40 1060 00ff e066 0f1f 8400 0000 0000| .@.`...f........                                                 
0x004004a0 |5dc3 0f1f 4000 662e 0f1f 8400 0000 0000| ]...@.f.........                                                 
0x004004b0 |be40 1060 0055 4881 ee40 1060 0048 c1fe| .@.`.UH..@.`.H..                                                 
0x004004c0 |0348 89e5 4889 f048 c1e8 3f48 01c6 48d1| .H..H..H..?H..H.                                                 
0x004004d0 |fe74 15b8 0000 0000 4885 c074 0b5d bf40| .t......H..t.].@                                                 
0x004004e0 |1060 00ff e00f 1f00 5dc3 660f 1f44 00  | .`......].f..D.                                                  
                                                                       ; [12] va=0x00400440 pa=0x00000440 sz=386 vsz= 
            0x004004ef  ~   00803d490b20   addb %al, 0x200b493d(%rax)
```

Pressing `dd` again disappears. After pressing `dd` again nothing happens. This happens with all new lines, but I think the bytes remain interpreted as code since they are disassembled. Plese show me ho can I do this in radare2. I haven't done this before in any disassembler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Cd` command for that:
`Cd[-] [size] [@addr] Hexdump data`
It will mark the selected block as a data.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Still interested if it can be done in visual mode too without typing the address.